# How can i only show the new or updated rows in a table in c# using sql?

Tags: c#, sql, gridview

Is there a way to only load the new or updated (edited) records in a table using Sql in C#? 
Suppose i have a table which consists of 1000 student records.I want to show this information in a gridview ( this is just an example ) and upon adding or editing new entries,I want the gridview to get updated and show the latest changes to the table.If i go and have a

> select *

statement ,This will definitely kill the application performance,So i thought its a good idea to try to add only those new records to the previously loaded records to the gridview.
But I'm clueless on the How to do such a task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no other solution then simply *architect*  you database.

Just one of many possible solutions: for every *inserted* or *updated* record in database you can have a `timestamp`. Having that information in database you can:

a) get the latest, from `timestamp` point of view, record in your `DataGrid`

b) get from darabase all reoirds that have `timestamp` bigger then it.

I repeat, this us just one of many possible solutions. What fits your requirements has to be decided by yourself.

Comment: Thankyou sir,Now how can i add these new records to an existing gridview?I mean currently what strikes me at the moment is,I create a third table, merge the resulting table and the current records shown in the gridview and then use this third table as the gridviews DataSource.Is it even wise or practical?What are the other solutions to this problem?

Comment: @Hossein: if you are talking about `DataTable`, just use `AddRow(..)` method. Why create another `DataTable` again?

Comment: I dont have a problem with adding,I'm just concerned about showing the latest changes along side the previous records in the gridview.You suggested using a timestap for showing New records, all i want is a way to add the new records to the ones currently showing in the gridview as fast as possible.Is what i'm looking for a bad idea or thought?I mean does it even make sense in first place ?

Comment: @Housen: it's very good idea. That's why you can use `timestamp` for *new* and *upated* rows.

Answer (score 3):

Create a timestamp column and store the "last updated" date. Within your application, store the last time the data was retrieved from the database. Then, you can select only the records that have changed (or been added) since then.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would be add a new field in the table such as **ModifyDate** of type datetime, and on insertion and updation of record put the current datetime in these field.

In that case you can select a query on the basis of this field as follows

```
Select Top 10 * from Table1 OrderBy ModifyDate desc
```